# why there is need of initiation of sum?

Tags: java

```
class CommandSum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a,b,c,i;
        int sum = 0 ;
        for( i = 0; i< args.length; i++)
        {
            a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            sum = a+b+c;            
        }   
        System.out.println("Command Line Sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

why there is need of initiation of  sum  ?

when sum initialize to 0 or other integer like 5 , answer remains same , why?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What is the problem?

Comment: Because the compiler cannot predict that the for loop is ever running.

Comment: I believe your `for` loop body should be `sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i])`. I'm not sure you really understand what is happening in your snippet. Try to give only two parameters to your program and see what is happening.

Comment: By the way, your `for` loop does not seem to be useful and will crash if you don't pass at least three integer arguments.

Answer (score 11):

Because if `args.length == 0`, your for loop won't execute. Java is preventing you from using `sum` without it being assigned a value.

If your for loop didn't execute, your code would effectively be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a,b,c,i;
    int sum; // assume you didn't assign anything

    // here sum would not be defined
    System.out.println("Command Line Sum is " + sum); 
}
```

---

**Side note**: your for loop doesn't currently use the `i` loop variable. Perhaps you meant:

```
for(i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {        
    sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
```

or simply:

```
for(String arg : args) {        
    sum += Integer.parseInt(arg);
}
```

Comment: ok but when sum initialize to 0 or other integers like 5 , answer remains same , why?

Comment: @user3753652 Presumably because you are passing three arguments. So  the line `sum = a+b+c;` completely overwrites the previous value of `sum`. If you rewrite your for loop like I suggest, then pass zero arguments to your method, you'll see that the initialized value *does* affect the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

> //why there is need of initiation of sum ?

If args.length is 0, your for loop is not executed.
You then reach the last line which uses `sum` ,  `System.out.println("Command Line Sum is " + sum);` ,  and `sum` would be uninitialized, which is not legal in Java.

> // when sum initialize to 0 or other integer like 5 , answer remains
>   same , why?

Presumably because you're testing with a case where `args.length` is >= 3, so you reach this line

```
sum = a+b+c;
```

which assigns a new value to `sum`